# My PC boots into a black screen, if not, it boots properly then freezes while in use

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi, freeze

My pc mostly boots into a black screen or doesn't boot at all. If it manages to boot it write something like;
SGX disabled by bios
psmouse ....
Recovering journal
/dev/sda2  clearing opharned anode...

Well this passes to quick I don't get to see clearly what is written.
I then sometimes continues to freeze in a screen like that of the attached picture.

If it manages to boot it freezes sometime after booting. It then takes some hours before it can at least boot to a black screen again.

It tried to go to the recovery mode but then it froze before I can do anything. I tried using or entering GRUB and it froze before I could do much.

How can I fix this?

PS: Its battery no longer works, so at school while I am maybe downloading software or updating/upgrading ubuntu not my software power to my pc would be cut off while it is yet to complete. I do so via the terminal.

I could not add the image since it is too large, hence I will write some of what is on the screen.

```
rmi_core videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops videobuf2_v4l2 videobuf2_common videodev mc hid_generic crc32_pclmul i2c_i801 r8169 intel_lpss_pci psmouse ahci i2c_smbus intel_lpss i2c_hid_acpi realtek libahci xhci_pci idma64 an I i2c_hid xhci_pci_renesas hid video pinctrl_sunrisepoint
```

````
[  17.981578] RIP: 0010:__pagevec_lru_add+0x19b/0x400
[  17.987842] RIP: 0010:mntput+0xb/0x40
[  17.993171] Code: 00 00 48 8b 75 b0 83 45 c4 01 8b 45 c4 0f b6 36 39 c6 0f 86 dc 01 00 00 48 63 45 c4 48 8b 4d b0 4c 8b 74 c1 08 48 85 th 74 29 <49> 8b 06 48 c1 e8 36 48 8b 04 c5 a0 5c e3 84 48 39 83 88 00 00 00
[  17.993179] RSP: 0000:ffffbd170028b930 EFLAGS: 00010086
[  17.999737] Code: 49 8b 47 68 4d 89 fe 48 83 e8 68 48 39 ca 75 9c e9 b1 fe ff ff e8 d5 ec 97 00 0f 1f 44 00 00 0f 1f 44 00 00 48 85 ff 74 1c 55 <8b> 87 0c 01 00 00 4c 8d 47 e0 48 89 e5 85 c0 75 0b 4c 89 c7 e8 7c
[  18.005120] RAX: 0000000000000004 RBX: ffff970343ab2000 RCX: ffff97038b5acce0
[  18.005126] RDX: ffffdee544524e48 RSI: 000000000000000f RDI: ffff970343ab2000
[  18.005132] RBP: ffffbd170028b9a0 R08: 0000000000000001 R09: 00000000000008a5
[  18.015120] RSP: 0018:ffffbd1700603be0 EFLAGS: 00010286
[  18.022733] R10: 0000000000000003 R11: 0000000000000001 R12: 0000000000000002
[  18.022737] R13: 0000000000000020 R14: ffefdee544524e80 R15: 0000000000000002
[  18.022756] FS: 00007fb8e027a980(0000) GS:ffff97038b580000(0000) knlGS: 0000000000000000
[  18.029489]
[  18.029489]
[  18.041510] CS: 0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000000050033
[  18.041515] CR2: 000055789606d098 CR3: 0000000102b08003 CR4: 00000000003706e0
[  18.041521] Call Trace:
[  18.041524] <TASK>
[  18.041527] ?__mod_lruvec_page_state+0x6b/0xb0
[  18.048898] RAX: 000000000000005d RBX: ffff97034ec47240 RCX: 0000005e00000000
[  18.055091] lru_cache_add+0x60/0x70
[  18.055116] add_to_page_cache_lru+0x78/0xd0
[  18.062490] RDX: 000000000000005d RSI: 0000005d00000000 RDI: ffef97034a04e7a0
[  18.068690] page_cache_ra_unbounded+0x1b1/0x210
[  18.068702] do_page_cache_ra+0x3d/0x40
[  18.076192] RBP: ffffbd1700603c08 R08: 000000000000005e R09: 0000000000000064
[  18.082498] ondemand_readahead+0x137/0x330
[  18.082588] page_cache_async_ra+0xa2/0xd0
[  18.082517] filemap_get_pages+0x21c/0x660
[  18.090118] R10: 0000000000000000 R11: 0000000000000024 R12: ffff9703422a8cc0
[  18.096445] filemap_read+0xbe/0x410
[  18.096455] ? __register_chrdev_region+0x312/0x4f0
[  18.104131] R13: ffffbd1700603cf0 R14: ffffbd1700603cf0 R15: ffffbd1700603e0c
[  18.110680] ? __path_openat+0x48b/0x1150
[  18.110691] generic_file_read_iter+0xe5/0x150
[  18.110703] ext4_file_read_iter+0x5b/0x180
[  18.118202] FS: 000071f3a96899880(0000) GS:ffff97038b500000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
[  18.124851] new_sync_read+0x113/0x1a0
[  18.124866] vfs_read+0xfe/0x1a0
[  18.132602] CS: 0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033```
````

Comment: It would help if you'd provide your hardware... Using Thinkpads for the last 20 years -I've never encountered these problems.. Ude the **edit** button to add the missing infos and do **not** add the specs into the comments

Comment: @kanehekili I have edited as requested. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Either you have a memory corruption or your harddisk is failing. Since your trace starts with

`?__mod_lruvec_page_state+0x6b/0xb0`

one must assume that a function in mem/memControl.c is called which leads to a page fault.

When starting grub(the linux bootloader) you have the change to select a memory check (press the shift button while starting):

[[image]]

Select the "mem test" (maybe over night, it might take some time). Report back when done.

[This](https://lore.kernel.org/lkml/20210816072147.3481782-1-chenhuang5@huawei.com/T/) shows a similar error in the module mentioned above

Comment: I don't have the option for memory test, instead I have; UEFI firmware settings option. And if I select it the pc restart to the same screen

Comment: If you do not have grub, you don't have linux. Mind my remark: **you will have to press the shift button** while starting.

Comment: I do have grub, I get the same screen as the one you have attached on your answer, the only difference is my screen does not have an option for memory test instead it has an option for uefi firmware settings. PS: I did press shift on boot(while starting)

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/memtest86+/+bug/883017 this link explains that ubuntu uefi systems do not have memtest